# Macbook Pro keeps shutting down even when magsafe is plugged

Tags: shutdown, logicboard, apple-diagnostics

I have MacBook Pro Retina Mid 2014 with Catalina installed. Initially my Mac is randomly shut down and later it shutdown every time I logged on to the Mac. It will display the desktop for a few seconds then shut down.

The Mac keeps shutting down in the Safe mode and also Recovery mode. But when I run Apple Diagnostic it says that there no errors found.

When I look in the log from advice in comments, I get "shutdown cause -128"

Do you think my logic board is broken or this is related to something else?

Comment: This might be a Hardware Failure issue but before tampering with that, try resetting the NVRAM/PRAM and SMC. Check out the two Apple Support articles showing how to do that. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063.           https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295

Comment: Let’s take a look at your logs.  See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/306722/119271) for some instructions on how to parse the log.  Update your question with the results and then we can move forward with finding you a solution.

Comment: @Allan I've tried it before and it returned -128. Anyway I'm gonna try solution described here https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/306714/macbook-pro-15-retina-mid-2014-random-shutdowns

Comment: -128 is hardware.  Disabling protection is the OS isn't going to fix what's inherently wrong with your Mac.  Check your memory - see:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/212810/119271.  If that's not it, you need to take it in for service.

Comment: Thanks for all links @Allan I'll try it one by one

Answer (score 0):

This could be a Hardware issue.

But you have these options that can help:

1) [Reset your Mac's NVRAM or PRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063).

2) If you continuing experiences issues, try to [reset the SMC of your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295).

I hope that works.